# How can you use the values of open/high/low/close of the first candle of the day as a variable in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to write a script in pine that would trigger a series of actions when the price breaches the high/low prices of the first 15 minute candle. How do I go about it?

I have come across the below code online:

```
study(title="OR", shorttitle="OpeningRange", overlay=true)
up15on = input(true, title="15 Minute Opening Range High")
down15on = input(true, title="15 Minute Opening Range Low")

is_newbar(res) => change(time(res)) != 0 

adopt(r, s) => security(syminfo.tickerid, r, s) 

high_range = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),high,0)
low_range = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),low,0)

high_rangeL = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),high,0) 
low_rangeL = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),low,0) 

up15 = plot(up15on ? adopt('15', high_rangeL): na, color = #53cbe9, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1) 
down15 = plot(down15on ? adopt('15', low_rangeL): na, color = #e97d53, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1) 

trans15 = up15on ?  97 : 100
fill(up15, down15, color = color.white, transp=trans15)
```

The above code plots the high/low as a line on the chart but I don't want the values to be plotted on the chart. I want those values as a variable. I am trying to figure out what this part does: `up15on ? adopt('15', high_rangeL): na, color = #53cbe9, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1`

I don't understand why there is a condition to check the up15on with adopt('15', high_rangeL). I would appreciate it if someone could explain it.

Modified code:

```
study(title="OR", shorttitle="OpeningRange", overlay=true)
up15on = input(true, title="15 Minute Opening Range High")
down15on = input(true, title="15 Minute Opening Range Low")

is_newbar(res) => change(time(res)) != 0 

adopt(r, s) => security(syminfo.tickerid, r, s) 

high_range = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),high,0)
low_range = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),low,0)


candle_color = close>adopt('15', high_range) ? color.purple :
 close<adopt('15', low_range) ? color.yellow :
 na

barcolor( candle_color )
```

Comment: Care to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please read my comment. I have edited it

Comment: The condition is just to toggle the plotting on/off depending whether you check `up15on` and/or `down15on` options in your study configuration options. These two are checkboxes in the configuration, as they are bool inputs.
The raw number you're looking for are the result of `adopt('15', high_rangeL)` and `adopt('15', low_rangeL)`.

I don't understand why to have high_range and high_rangeL, nor why low_range and low_range_L, given they are identical expressions and the two variables without 'L' are not used anywhere, though

Comment: Oh, and also: you're getting a plot because plot function is being called. Note that without plot one cannot look upon the value of variables in a Pine script. Bringing values to chart, either plotting or with any other graphical resource, are the only visual way you have to check upon values - if you want to see them at all.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified my code a bit to change the color of the first candle that breaches the high and low of the first 15 minute candle but it appears to color all the subsequent candles as well. How do I stop the other candles from getting colored?

Comment: I suggest you try to use `barcolor()` function as per documentation (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_barcolor). That is, all the expression you use when assigning `candle_color`. Also, I suggest you assign a color type to the else case instead of `na`.